# Dictionary count vowels

Tags: dictionary, count

Write a function count_vowels which takes a string s as input and returns a dictionary where the keys are the vowels that are present in s, and the values of the dictionary are the number of times each vowel is found in s.
Your function should convert the string to lowercase before counting letters.
For the purpose of this exercise the vowels are 'aeiou'.
For example, for the string:
'It was the best of times, it was the worst of times.'
your function should return:
{'i': 4, 'a': 2, 'e': 5, 'o': 3}

Comment: Stackoverflow is for asking "what is wrong with what I have?"... you won't get a great response for effectively asking "can you do it for me?"

Comment: count_vowels = {'a':x , 'e':x ,'i':x ,'o':x ,'u': x}
    print("keys" + ":", x)

Comment: this is what I had but I not sure